# (A*) Pathfinding

Tags: c#, .net, path-finding

**(A*) Pathfinding**

Only for up,down,left,right

Anyways, I'm not sure, I've checked some examples, but, will it be like this?:

```
Point StartTile;
Point EndTile;
List<Point> CheckedPoints;
List<Point> UncheckedPoints;
```

So, I will add the **StartTile** to **UncheckedPoints**.

I'll cycle through **UncheckedPoints**, and add the (Up, Down, Left, Right) tiles to **UncheckedPoints**, if it's not in **CheckedPoints**. And remove the point I just checked, and add it to **CheckedPoints**.

I'll do the same until I get to **EndTile** in **UncheckedPoints**, then what?

**1 What if I can't get to the EndTile, will it cycle on forever? How can I prevent this?**

**2 If I can't get to the EndTile, is there a way to get the closest tile to the EndTile?**

**3 How can I get the list of tiles from StartTile to EndTile? Keeping a long list for each cycle will take loads of memory, right?**

Comment: I just need the answer to question number 3, but the other two would also help me.

Comment: Um, you're talking about A* (pronounced A Star)? That's a pathfinding algorithm, though only one of many.

Comment: Yea, but I thought A* was Up, Down, Left, Right, and the four corners. I don't want the corners, so.. I named it A+ algorithm. Anyways what I need help with is A* algorithm without the corners. Fixed

Comment: I don't need code, I can make that, but can someone explain question **3** to me(and/or the other two)?

Comment: You are best off asking this over on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: It doesn't need much memory. If you already have a list of tiles, which i guess you have for various other reasons. You only need the index or maybe the reference to the passed tile.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth **No**, cstheory.SE is for *research*-level questions. A simple question on a well-known algorithm is perfectly in line for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 What if I can't get to the EndTile, will it cycle on forever? How can I prevent this?

No, the algorithm should only run, as long as there are UncheckedPoints. You can abort, once it reachs EndTile, but that is not necessary.

And you must never add a point to UncheckedPoints that is already contained in CheckedPoints

> 2 If I can't get to the EndTile, is there a way to get the closest tile to the EndTile?

Yes, since you store all visited ppints in CheckedPoints, you can choose the closest point among them.

> 3 How can I get the list of tiles from StartTile to EndTile? Keeping a long list for each cycle will take loads of memory, right?

You can store for each point, from which point it was visited.

This will double the needed memory, but it will not be "loads of memory", since you already have to store all visited points anyways, to avoid running in loops.

--

You might want to look at Dijkstra's algorithm on a grid (not on a graph), which is simpler. A* is only an optimization   to not explore all the titles in a kind of random order, but to first explore the titles that are closest to the end tile.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the answers were right in front of me. Just didn't think of these.